# rest_cannot_create for none admin wordpress api v2

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, jwt

this is error

i use jwt authentication plugin

```
# BEGIN WordPress
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteBase /badamsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /badamsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and this error

```
 {
        "code": "rest_cannot_create",
        "message": "با عرض پوزش، شما اجازهٔ ایجاد نوشته با این نام کاربری را ندارید. ",
        "data": {
            "status": 403
        }
    }
```

[image]

**but when I send request with administator it work ):**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code instead of above in

> .htaccess

file

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteBase /badamsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /badamsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```